# A security concern with H2

Tags: security, encryption, h2

**Note:** Though I'm mentioning H2, this may apply to any DBMS,

1. that allows you to store the whole database in a single file; **and**
2. that makes its source-code publicly available.

**My concern:**

Is it possible to break into an encrypted H2 database by doing something like the following?

1. Store a very large, zeroed out BLOB, a few 100 KB in size, in some table.
2. Examine the new H2 database file binary and look for a repeating pattern near page/block boundaries. The page/block size could be obtained from the H2 source code. The repeating pattern so obtained would be the cipher key used to encrypt the H2 database.
3. Once the cipher key stands exposed, the hacker just needs to be dedicated enough to then further dig into the H2 sources and figure out the exact structure of its tables, columns, and rows. In other words, everything stands exposed from this point on.

I have not personally studied the source code of H2, nor am I a cryptography expert, but here's why I think the above -- or some hack along the above lines -- might work:

1. For performance reasons, all DBMSes read/write data in chunks (pages or blocks 512 bytes to 8 KB in size), and so would H2.
2. Since a BLOB several hundred KB in size would far exceed the DBMS's page/block size, one can expect the cryptogrphic key (generated internally using the user password) to show up in repeating patterns of sizes less than the page/block size.

Comment: Any cipher exposing the described behaviour is broken by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file encryption algorithm used in H2 does not use the [ECB encryption mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). The file encryption algorithm is, [as documented](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#security_protocols), not vulnerable to this kind of attack. The [new storage engine](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html) that will be used for future versions of H2 uses the [standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEX-TCB-CTS#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29) [AES XTS algorithm](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#encryption).

Answer (score 4):

A good cryptography algorithm will not be vulnerable to this attack.

The patterns in the plaintext (here the BLOB of zeroes) will be dissipated in the ciphertext. The secret key will not be readily visible in the ciphertext as patterns or otherwise. A classic technique to achieve that when using a block cipher is to make the encryption of a block dependent on the ciphertext of the previous block. Here the blocks I'm referring to are the blocks used in the cryptography algorithm, typically 128 bits of length.

You can for example XOR the plaintext block with the result of the previous block encryption, here is the schema from Wikipedia for CBC mode, which XOR the current block with the result of the previous one prior to encryption.

[image: CBC mode]

As you can see, even if you feed all zeroes in each plaintext blocks, you will end up with a completely random looking result.

These are just examples and the actual confusion mechanism used in H2 might be more complex or involved depending on the algorithm they use.

Comment: But even though each crypto block would be different in CBC, for a database page as a whole (which would be typically > crypto block), I do expect to see repeating patterns. My concern was not so much about the soundness of the cipher algo, but rather how H2 may be using it to prevent an attack of the type described above. Because H2's source code is publicly available, any hacker can find out the obfuscation mechanism being used, and hence... the concern.

Comment: It is possible and desirable to use a scheme where two database pages containing the same data will not yield the same ciphertext. This is clear for example when using disk encryption software like TrueCrypt, where 512-byte disk sectors will often contain the same data but should encrypt to different ciphertexts.

Comment: The fact that the code is open source is a good thing in theory, everything should be public except the key. We can posit that the attacker would have access to the proprietary code anyway, so it better be public and peer reviewed. I'll try to dig up what encryption is used in H2, hopefully AES-XTS or similar. The implementation is indeed often the weakest spot though.

Comment: Thanks. H2 does allow the specification of `"CIPHER=AES"` in the connection URL. I'd like to know how H2 is avoiding the repetition of patterns for data sequences 2x, 3x, 4x, ... the crypto block size. Also, is it okay security-wise if there are repeating patterns **within** the same page? E.g., a zeroed out BLOB when stored across pages would give different ciphertexts for different pages, but I'm concerned about patterns repeating within the same page.